# How to change a view property in CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have CustomAdapter extending ArrayAdapter, in which I set some views inside LinearLayout - one row, like this (adapter):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    . . .
    ImageView statePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.state);
    statePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_green);
    return view;
}
```

This works fine. But now I want to bind a context menu on item in my list, so I have something like this (main activity - listActivity):

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case CM_START:
        View view = getListAdapter().getView(info.position, null, null);
        ImageView statePic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.state);
        // I'm sure this view is the right one

        statePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_grey);
        view.invalidate();
        view.refreshDrawableState();
        return true;

    case CM_STOP:
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

What I want to achieve with this snippet is to change image in that item, but this doesn not work (view is not refreshed with the new value). How can I do that?

Comment: Please use the `android-listview` tag instead of `listview` :)

Comment: ok, sorry about that :-)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the binding of the ContextMenu not work or changing the resource in the ImageView?

Comment: Binding works correctly, changing the resource does not work. Or refreshing that view - if I read from the same view, there is right resource set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the targetView property of the AdapterContextMenuInfo class:

```
...
ImageView statePic = (ImageView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.state);
...
```